# How to fix error on Xcode 9.2. Lexical or processor issue. 'mscorlib_System_Object2689449295.h' file not found

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, xcode9.2

Tried almost all solutions I found on forums, I build the Xcode on Windows and move it to the MAC and this happens. I did same thing for all my previous games and worked fine but this time this strange issue happened.
Unity 2017.2.0f3, Xcode_9.2.